# Python: asynchronous requests with Single-Sign On HTTP Negotiate authentication

Tags: python, authentication, soap, zeep

I have been able to make synchronous requests to a SOAP service via `Zeep` and authenticating using the `HttpNegotiateAuth` from `requests_negotiate_sspi`. I now need to make asynchronous requests, and `Zeep` suggests using `httpx` to support this. However, the `httpx` package does not support requests_negotiate_sspi auth as is. Has anyone found a way around this?

Alternatively, does anyone have any suggestions for packages that would provide asynchronous requests and also support something like requests_negotiate_sspi (Single-Sign On HTTP Negotiate authentication using the requests library on Windows).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

While I eventually realised I didn't need to do asynchronous requests, I solved the above by extracting the SOAP body generated by Zeep using `client.create_message()`, then using grequests which can support the HttpNegotiateAuth auth.

Making sure you use the headers as below:

```
headers = {'SOAPAction':SOAPAction, 'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'}
```